# Фото альбом на javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер! Не могу понять скрипт, как вставить файлы, куда прописывать и как?

```
< script >
var marker;
var mas = new Array();
var hiddenImg;
var t;
hiddenImg = new Image();
//marker=287;
marker = 0;
mas[0] = 287;
mas[1] = 288;
mas[2] = 292;
mas[3] = 293;
mas[4] = 294;
mas[5] = 295;
mas[6] = 297;
mas[7] = 298;
mas[8] = 300;
mas[9] = 301;
mas[10] = 302;
mas[11] = 303;
mas[12] = 304;
mas[13] = 305;
mas[14] = 307;
mas[15] = 308;
mas[16] = 309;
mas[17] = 310;
mas[18] = 311;
mas[19] = 312;
mas[20] = 313;
mas[21] = 314;
mas[22] = 315;
mas[23] = 316;
mas[24] = 317;
mas[25] = 318;
mas[26] = 319;
mas[27] = 320;
mas[28] = 321;
mas[29] = 322;
mas[30] = 353;
mas[31] = 354;
mas[32] = 355;
mas[33] = 356;
mas[34] = 357;
mas[35] = 358;
mas[36] = 359;
mas[37] = 360;
mas[38] = 361;
mas[39] = 362;
mas[40] = 363;
mas[41] = 364;
mas[42] = 366;
mas[43] = 367;
mas[44] = 368;
mas[45] = 369;
mas[46] = 370;
mas[47] = 371;

function backward() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    marker--;
    if (marker < 0) marker = mas.length - 1;
    hiddenImg.src = "getimage.asp?IsFullImage=yes&imgID=" + mas[marker];
/*if (hiddenImg.complete)
alert ("ok");
else
alert ("no!");*/
    while (!hiddenImg.src) {}
    t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('img').src=hiddenImg.src;", 1);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = (marker + 1) + " из " + mas.length;
    document.getElementById("count2").innerHTML = (marker + 1) + " из " + mas.length;
    //alert (mas.length+" "+marker);
}

function forward() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    marker++;
    if (marker > mas.length - 1) marker = 0;
    hiddenImg.src = "getimage.asp?IsFullImage=yes&imgID=" + mas[marker];
/*if (hiddenImg.complete)
alert ("ok");
else
alert ("no!");*/
    //usleep (100);
    while (!hiddenImg.src) {}
    t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('img').src=hiddenImg.src;", 1);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = (marker + 1) + " из " + mas.length;
    document.getElementById("count2").innerHTML = (marker + 1) + " из " + mas.length;
    //alert (mas.length+" "+marker);
} < /script>

<center>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="backward()">Назад</a > : 
< span id = "count" > 1из48 < /span> : 
<a href="javascript:" onclick="forward()">Вперед</a >
< br > 
< a href = "javascript:" onclick = "forward()" >
    < img id = "img" src = "getimage.asp?IsFullImage=yes&imgID=287" border = 0 > 
< /a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="backward()">Назад</a > : 
< span id = "count2" > 1из48 < /span> : 
<a href="javascript:" onclick="forward()">Вперед</a > 
< /center>
```

Comment: Код ужасный и нечитабельный, исправьте пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт предполагает, что картинку вернет скрипт *getimage.asp*

```
hiddenImg.src = "getimage.asp?IsFullImage=yes&imgID=" + mas[marker];
```

после чего она назначается image-у на странице:

```
t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('img').src=hiddenImg.src;", 1);
```